# Is there any way to tell Validator to validate the fields for all the default constraint validation which are not annotated with @Email,@NotNull etc

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, bean-validation

I've a class Student

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "new_age")
    private Integer newAge;
}
```

and when I use

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
                .configure()
                .buildValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
Student student = new Student(1L,"wec","D23d",15);
validator.validate(student);
```

I get the expected result like

ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must be a well-formed email address', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class com.example.SomeMainClass.model.Student, messageTemplate='{jakarta.validation.constraints.Email.message}'}

Is there any way to achieve this without using @Email in Student class?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to pass the information on constraints one way or the other. If you are looking for an alternative method of defining constraints (not annotations), you might want to take a look at the [programmatic constraint definition here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api).
In your example, you'd have your `Student` class without constraints.

```
class Student {
    private Long id;
    private String fullName;
    private String email;
    private Integer newAge;
}
```

and then you programmatically define them like:

```
// get an instance of a HibernateValidatorConfiguration 
HibernateValidatorConfiguration config = Validation.byProvider( HibernateValidator.class ).configure();

// create a new mapping which to configure constraints 
ConstraintMapping newMapping = config.createConstraintMapping();
// configure Student constraints through the DSL:
newMapping
        .type( Student.class )
        .field( "email" )
        .constraint( new EmailDef() );

// add the constraints configuration back to the validator configuration:
config.addMapping( newMapping );
// create an instance of a validator based on the configured mapping:
Validator validator = config.buildValidatorFactory().getValidator();

// do the validation 
Set<ConstraintViolation<Student>> violations = validator.validate( new Student( 1L, "name", "email", 1 ) );
```

alternatively if you don't want to use a programmatic approach -- you could do the same [through XML](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/3.0/jakarta-bean-validation-spec-3.0.html#xml-mapping-constraintdeclarationinxml)

---

**UPDATE:**
From additional questions asked under this answer -- Bean Validation has a way to validate values, but it still requires a bean class with constraints applied to it:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validateValue(Class<T> beanType,
                                              String propertyName,
                                              Object value,
                                              Class<?>... groups);
```

So to get something close to what you've been asking you'd still need to have a class with defined constraints:

```
public class Constraints {
        @Email
        String email;
        
        // ... other properties with constraints 
}
```

and then using a validator instance you'd call:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Constraints>> constraintViolations = validator.validateValue(
        Constraints.class, // class that contains constraint definitions
        "email",           // property from that class to "chose" which constraints will be checked 
        "some@email"       // value to check
);
```

Since bean validation is about validating beans you'd need to have a bean with constrains one way or the other...

Comment: If I use JOOQ for creating dynamic table during the run time, then is it possible to use these constraints while inserting values to that table by using the above method or any other method.

Comment: If you have a class with properties in it, and you know what the property names are, then -- sure using programmatic definition should work. I don't think that Jooq is integrated with Bean Validation - so you'd need to do that part either manually as in the example above or in your original example. Or since you've mentioned spring in your tags -- you might leverage the method parameter validation and validate the input parameters...But that would be a different question now ;)

Comment: Here we are passing the class name and the field to which the constraint have to be checked. I'm looking for a method to which we can pass the value and constraint so that the value can be checked for that validation(without providing the class name). For example, if I use
validator.validate("email", Email.class); or validator.validate("email"); then the email validation can be checked on the provided value. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: updated the answer since that wouldn't fit the comment ;)